# On non jailbreak iphone,Can I run a binary in my Application bundle directory?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, sandbox

I have an executable binary file in my App folder. I want to use this App to run this code and I have signed the code with my certificate. But I don't know how to launch it. Fork, execvl and posix_spawn are forbidden by the SandBox profile. Is there any other way to launch it?

Comment: Do you have sources for the binary?

Comment: @ckhan,no!but,I am sure,it is a mach-o  and arm format binary.So,do you know how to launch it through my app?thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. As you say the sandbox profile prohibits it.